# Can NerdDinner be run on XP with IIS5?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm slowly modernizing:  Can I run the ASP MVC example [NerdDinner](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/) on my XP Pro system?  I know there is a possible issue with IIS5.1 being too old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this](http://www.ee99ee.com/blog/2009/02/08/how-to-get-aspnet-mvc-working-under-iis-51-on-windows-xp/)

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to try to play with the code? Then the build-in asp.net development server will work. If you want to host it on IIS 5.1 on Win XP Pro, I didn't see a reason why you want to do that.

Comment: I hosted a bunch of websites from my XP machine (back in the day).